# Admin Configuration page showing Error: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in Iterator.php on line 59

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

> On the Admin > Store > Configuration page, Showing Below Error

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 59
```

> I have tried Below Steps but still facing same error.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: this error is coming `System.xml ` incorrect tab id

Comment: In which folder's System.xml?

Comment: you have custom create extension yaa another third party extension installed

Comment: I have not installed any extension or create any module. I just install working project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solved by this way

Checked `App > etc > Config.php` to check any disabled module

Found 2 disabled modules. I have enabled it and then run:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Issue is resolved, This issue occur because these disabled modules are used into configuration as TAB.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears when the system.xml of any module has reference to a tab id which Magento is not able to find.

For example:

```
<section id="custom_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <class>separator-top</class>
    <label>Custom Section</label>
    <tab>customtab</tab>
    ...
</section>
```

This issue appears due to 2 major reasons.

1. The **system.xml** file has **wrong tab ID**.
2. The tab ID referenced in the **system.xml** file is in some other module which is not present because it is part of another git branch or it is disabled.

To resolve this error, you can do the following:

1. Check for the module which has the referenced tab ID in other branches. If it exists, either make that module part of current git branch or add the following lines in the system.xml of your module just below the opening  tag, which is generating the error:

.

```
<tab id="customtab" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
    <label>Custom Tab</label>
</tab>
```

2. Or correct the spelling of your tab ID.